# Group results only if a condition is met in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to group results only if the user id and month creation date are the same?

| user_id | rank | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 2021-12-06 14:11:14 |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-11-06 14:11:14 |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-12-06 14:11:14 |

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table_name
GROUP BY
    user_id,
    DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%m-%y')
ORDER BY
    rank DESC
```

With the query what I get is as follows

| user_id | rank | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 2021-12-06 14:11:14 |

and what I need is to obtain the following result:

> Because the records are from different months: 2021-12-06 14:11:14 - 2021-11-06 14:11:14

| user_id | rank | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 2021-12-06 14:11:14 |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-11-06 14:11:14 |

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aBgB6QdMGe3ZmX65u9mXFC/0

Comment: You seem to want the highest rank per user per month so a max(rank) would be appropriate and you can perhaps lose the order by. NB Rank is a reserved word in version 8 and above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want the highest rank per user per month so a max(rank) would be appropriate , also group_by without aggregate functions is not appropriate.

```
DROP table if exists t;

create table t
(user_id int,   rnk int,    created_at datetime);
insert into t values
(1, 3   ,'2021-12-06 14:11:14'),
(1, 1   ,'2021-11-06 14:11:14'),
(1, 2   ,'2021-12-06 14:11:14');

sELECT
    t.user_id,max(t.rnk) `rank` ,DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%m-%y') ym
FROM
    t
GROUP BY
    user_id,
    DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%m-%y')
ORDER BY
    `rank` DESC

+---------+------+-------+
| user_id | rank | ym    |
+---------+------+-------+
|       1 |    3 | 12-21 |
|       1 |    1 | 11-21 |
+---------+------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: thanks, the initial problem was at the record level, the query was correct. But I like the way of how to get the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Below Query Products the output that you required.

```
SELECT
    user_id,rank,
    created_at
FROM
    table_name
GROUP BY
    user_id,
    created_at
ORDER BY
    rank DESC
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aBgB6QdMGe3ZmX65u9mXFC/1

Comment: Yes, I had the wrong records D:, thanks.

Comment: This use of `GROUP BY` is incompatible with `sql_mode=only_full_group_by`. The mode was added as default in MySQL 5.7.5. `GROUP BY` is intended to be used with aggregate functions. See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aBgB6QdMGe3ZmX65u9mXFC/2